# how to retrict user to call function with only new operator?

Tags: javascript

```
 function person(name){
      if(new.target){
        new throw('Please call with new operator')
      }
      this.name = name

    }

    var a = new person(); // correct wy

    person(); // will give error to user
```

Can we restrict user to call function with only  `new` .if he call without `new` operator he will get `error`
I tried like above

can you suggest the better way ?

Comment: why you need this use case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) exists only when called with `new`. The condition should be `!new.target`:

```js
function Person(name) {
  if (!new.target) throw ('Please call with new operator')
  this.name = name
}

var a = new Person('Moses');

console.log(a);

Person();
```

Another option is to use an [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Trying to invoke a class as a function will throw an error:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var a = new Person('Moses');

console.log(a);

Person();
```